# Windows 7 vs Windows 10 Cookie Handling

Tags: excel, cookies, windows-7, windows-10, webdav

Okay, so I'm lost on this one. And I assume this is entirely an OS issue, so what I'm really asking for is confirmation and details on this issue.

On Windows 7, I am able to open Internet Explorer 11, browse to a site, set a cookie, close the browser, open Excel 2013, browse to a file hosted on a WebDAV at the some domain and have that cookie send to the server.

But on Windows 10... following the exact same process (using either IE11 or Edge), and using Excel 2013... the cookie will not be sent! In fact the cookie is only re-sent if the same application that set it is used to make the request.

So are cookies application specific now in Windows 10? Does anyone have any insight on this? Is there any registry hack or setting that will allow cookies to function as they used to in Windows 7?

I have an existing WebApp that relies on the fact the cookies set in the browser will carry over to when the same site is accessed from Excel. Basically we launch Excel with the WebDAV file location, but the WebApp is the one setting the cookie (the cookie is set via JavaScript).